# Does Linux go to sleep and pause the calculations when jupyter notebook is calculating?

Tags: linux, sleep, jupyter-notebook, logout

Is it possible to leave the computer over night with some calculations in jupyter notebook and get the results in the morning even if Linux logs out after a while? Will it go to sleep and pause the jupyter notebook calculations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof by experience which I want to share.

Linux does indeed log out, but jupyter notebook calculations run further and Linux does not go to sleep unless they are done. If you wake the computer in the morning, you will find the finished calculations with all variables still in memory.